# Python regex search for hexadecimal bytes

Tags: python, regex, binary, seek

I'm trying to search a binary file for a series of hexadecimal values, however, I've run into a few issues that I can't quite solve. (1) I'm not sure how to search the entire file and return all the matches. Currently I have f.seek going only as far as I think the value might be, which is no good. (2) I'd like to return the offset in either decimal or hex where there might be a match, although I get 0 each time, so I'm not sure what I did wrong.

**example.bin**

```
AA BB CC DD EE FF AB AC AD AE AF BA BB BC BD BE
BF CA CB CC CD CE CF DA DB DC DD DE DF EA EB EC
```

**code:**

```
# coding: utf-8
import struct
import re

with open("example.bin", "rb") as f:
    f.seek(30)
    num, = struct.unpack(">H", f.read(2))
hexaPattern = re.compile(r'(0xebec)?')
m = re.search(hexaPattern, hex(num))
if m:
   print "found a match:", m.group(1)
   print " match offset:", m.start()
```

Maybe there's a better way to do all this?

Comment: how big is the file?

Comment: File could range in size from 100 KB to 10 MB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. I'm not sure how to search the entire file and return all the matches.
> 2. I'd like to return the offset in either decimal or hex

```
import re

f = open('data.txt', 'wb')
f.write('\xAA\xBB\xEB\xEC')
f.write('\xAA\xBB\xEB\xEC')
f.write('\xAA\xBB\xEB\xEC')
f.write('\xAA\xBB\xEB\xEC')
f.write('\xAA\xBB\xEB\xEC')
f.write('\xAA\xBB\xEB\xEC')
f.write('\xAA\xBB\xEB\xEC')
f.close()

f = open('data.txt', 'rb')
data = f.read()
f.close()

pattern = "\xEB\xEC"
regex = re.compile(pattern)

for match_obj in regex.finditer(data):
    offset = match_obj.start()
    print "decimal: {}".format(offset)
    print "hex(): " + hex(offset)
    print 'formatted hex: {:02X} \n'.format(offset)

--output:--
decimal: 2
hex(): 0x2
formatted hex: 02 

decimal: 6
hex(): 0x6
formatted hex: 06 

decimal: 10
hex(): 0xa
formatted hex: 0A 

decimal: 14
hex(): 0xe
formatted hex: 0E 

decimal: 18
hex(): 0x12
formatted hex: 12 

decimal: 22
hex(): 0x16
formatted hex: 16 

decimal: 26
hex(): 0x1a
formatted hex: 1A
```

The positions in the file use 0 based indexing like a list.

> **e.finditer(pattern, string, flags=0)**
>   Return an iterator yielding MatchObject instances over all
>   non-overlapping matches for the RE pattern in string. The string is
>   scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found.
>
> **Match objects** support the following methods and attributes:
>   start([group])
>   end([group])
>   Return the indices of the start and end of
>   the substring matched by group;  group defaults to zero (meaning the
>   whole matched substring).

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: nice, that works out quite well. thanks for the explanation, very helpful!

Comment: @DIF, If you don't want the '0x' in front of the offset hex string, you can use format(): `print '{:02X}'.format(offset)` (also creates two digits for all hex codes).

Answer (score 1):

try

```
import re

with open("example.bin", "rb") as f:
    f1 = re.search(b'\xEB\xEC', f.read())

print "found a match:", f1 .group()
print " match offset:", f1 .start()
```

Comment: thanks, that's almost perfect. is there a way to make the f1.group() display as hexadecimal?

Comment: Print `f1.group()` as hexadecimal: `print(f1.group().hex())`.